# Check column data type and change it in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

All I want to do is check if the `hire_state` column's data type is `bit`, and if so, change it to `SmallInt`.

Here is my code

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.employees') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.employees
    (
        employees_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
        employees_number INT NOT NULL,
        first_name NVARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
        last_name NVARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
        birthday DATE NOT NULL,
        gender TINYINT NOT NULL,
        hire_date DATE NOT NULL,
        phone1 NCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        phone2 NVARCHAR(25),
        home_address NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        granty NVARCHAR(250),
        hire_state BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
        leave_Date DATE,
        job SMALLINT NOT NULL
    );
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                   WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = N'employees' 
                     AND C.COLUMN_NAME = 'employee_image')
        ALTER TABLE dbo.employees 
            ADD employee_image NVARCHAR(255)

    ALTER TABLE dbo.employees 
        ALTER COLUMN hire_state TINYINT NOT NULL 
END;
```

How can I check whether `hire_state` is bit or not and then change it to `TinyInt`?

When I execute my code shown above, I get this error

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 49
> The object 'DF__employees__hire___267ABA7A' is dependent on column 'hire_state'.
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 49
> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN hire_state failed because one or more objects access this column.

I did not use `hire_state` in any other table

Comment: `hire_state` has a `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT`; you need to `DROP` that constraint first and then recreate it.

Comment: and how check first is bit or not

Comment: *"and how check first is bit or not"* huh? `first_name` is an `nvarchar` in your example and defining it as a `bit` would be a terrible idea.

Comment: hire_state is bit

Comment: Checking for existance of `hire_state` as a `bit` column can be done with this: `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name = N'hire_state' AND object_id  = OBJECT_ID('dbo.employees') AND system_type_id = 104)` - but to modify it, you'd have to find out the name of the default constraint first, and drop that

Comment: @marc_s . . . Using the system views (with schema `sys`) seems to be pretty cryptic. Is there a special reason to prefer those instead of the views in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema?

Comment: @BartHofland: the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views are a very generic approach which was designed to work with many databases - but as such, they only provide the minimal information, and they're "over-engineered" (hard to use). I much prefer the SQL Server specific, targeted and complete `sys` catalog views

Comment: @marc_s . . . I understand. And I partly agree. But then I would at least use `TYPE_ID('bit')` instead of the magical number 104 in the query. Makes it more readable imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I Change my code base on comment and it work

```
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 
    N'hire_state' AND 
   object_id= OBJECT_ID('dbo.employees') AND  
   system_type_id = 104)
   BEGIN 
     ALTER TABLE dbo.employees DROP CONSTRAINT DF__employees__hire___267ABA7A 
     ALTER TABLE dbo.employees ALTER COLUMN  hire_state TINYINT NOT NULL 
   END;
```